# Proxy JavaScript

Tags: javascript, наследование

js

```
const persona1 = {
       name: 'bingus',
       age: '5 year',
       job: false,
    }
    const persona2 = {
       name: 'floppa',
       age: '5 year',
       job: false,
    }
    
    const handler = {
       get( target , prop){
          console.log(`this ${prop} target value: ${target[prop]}`);
          return target;
       }
    }
    
    Object.prototype.morePersonInfo = new Proxy( Object 'как его менять динамически?' , handler); // пытался так, но по понятным на то причинам, это не сработало
```

Как динамично применять proxy для объектов?
Очень нуждаюсь в вашей помощи.

пример console:

persona1.morePersonInfo // вывод того что мне нужно через proxy для persona1

persona2.morePersonInfo // вывод того что мне нужно через proxy для persona2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не уверен, правильно ли я понимаю. Если вы хотите, чтобы при обращении к любому свойству любого объекта происходило обращение к прокси без какого-либо вмешательства в сам объект, то это вряд ли возможно. Наверное, вы бы хотели превратить `Object.prototype` в прокси, но это невозможно, потому что `Object.prototype` только для чтения.

Так что у вас есть выбор: 1) назначить прототипом всех нужных объектов ваше Proxy — но этого делать не рекомендуют, так как изменение прототипа может замедлить работу с объектом и само по себе является медленной операцией; 2) сразу задать прототипом прокси через `__proto__` в литерале — но зачем такая сложность, если можно просто создавать объекты как проксированные?

Не это ли вам нужно?

```js
const handler = {
  get(target , prop){
    console.log(`this ${prop} target value: ${target[prop]}`);
    return target[prop];
  }
};

const persona1 = new Proxy({
  name: 'bingus',
  age: '5 year',
  job: false,
}, handler);

const persona2 = new Proxy({
  name: 'floppa',
  age: '5 year',
  job: false,
}, handler);

persona1.morePersonInfo;
persona2.morePersonInfo;
```

Comment: да, мне нужно было примерно так, но динамически к каждому объекту.

Comment: Я ведь правильно понял, что можно просто создать класс, сделать на него target и уже на основе него создавать другие классы которые в свою очередь будут наследоваться от него с таргетом?  (простите за мыло мыльное , не могу красиво сформулировать)

Comment: А, к сожалению так нельзя сделать

Comment: просто оборачивать каждый объект в proxy такое себе занятие.

Answer (score 1):

Технически, можно использовать [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) чтобы получить что-то подобное... Внутри геттера `this` будет ссылаться на текущий объект.

```js
const person1 = {
  name: 'bingus',
  age: '5 year',
  job: false,
};

const person2 = {
  name: 'floppa',
  age: '5 year',
  job: false,
};

Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "morePersonInfo", {
  get() {
    console.log("*", this);
    return this.name + ', ' + this.age;
  }
});

console.log( person1.morePersonInfo );
console.log( person2.morePersonInfo );
```

```css
code { white-space: nowrap !important }
```

Но все эти прокси, геттеры и прочая экзотика используются в очень редких случаях. Например, когда уже написано много кода с использованием одного свойства, а вдруг оказалось, что это свойство должно выдать какое-то специфичное значение в определенных условиях. Может быть удобнее заменить его на геттер, чем всё переписать.

Если функция и так заранее предусмотрена, было бы уместно явно сделать её методом этих объектов, а не замаскировать её под свойтво. А для этого есть такие варианты:

1. Вручную выдать им свойство-функцию (не очень удобно):

```js
function morePersonInfo() {
  return this.name + ', ' + this.age;
}

const person1 = {
  name: 'bingus',
  age: '5 year',
  morePersonInfo, // Вместо morePersonInfo: morePersonInfo
  // Сокращение работает, когда названия свойства и значения одинаковые.
};

const person2 = {
  name: 'floppa',
  age: '5 year',
  morePersonInfo, 
};

console.log( person1.morePersonInfo() );
console.log( person2.morePersonInfo() );
```

2. Создать объект с набором методов и сделать его "родительским" для ваших объектов:

```js
const person = (function() {

  const _methods = {
    morePersonInfo() {
      return this.name + ', ' + this.age;
    },
    moo() {
      console.log("Moo...");
    },
  };

  return function(obj) {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, _methods);
    return obj;
  }

})();

const person1 = person({
  name: 'bingus',
  age: '5 year',
});

const person2 = person({
  name: 'floppa',
  age: '5 year',
});

person1.moo();
console.log( person2.morePersonInfo() );
```

3. Изначально создавать объекты с помощью [Классов](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

```js
class Person {

  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.job = false;
  }

  morePersonInfo() {
    return this.name + ', ' + this.age;
  }
  
  moo() {
    console.log("Moo...");
  }

}

const person1 = new Person('bingus', '5 year');
const person2 = new Person('floppa', '5 year');

person1.moo();
console.log( person2.morePersonInfo() );
```

Конечно, из таких примеров не очевидно, какой вариант выбрать. Нужно рассматривать это всё в контексте конкретной задачи.